# the ID is taking over my class when im using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been sitting with this problem for like 2 hours. What I'm trying to make is a website where you push a button and it changes color. I know this can be done with CSS, but I'm not interested in that.

The main problem is that when I push the button, nothing happens.. However, if I remove the ' #sug from the css' everything works perfectly...  So what I want to do, is to make the layout very basic at the beginning, so there's nothing to it, except like the black background, and when I push the buttons it should switch..

Also, I know you can implement `onclick` in the button tag, but that's not what I'm going for either. I want to know WHY this happens and how I can resolve this problem.

Here's my javascript, CSS and HTML code:

```js
window.onload = setUp;

function setUp() {
  document.getElementById("normal").onclick = setNormalStyle;
  document.getElementById("crazy").onclick = setCoolStyle;
  document.getElementById("insane").onclick = setInsaneStyle;
}

function setNormalStyle() {
  var messageBox = document.getElementById("sug");
  messageBox.className = "normal";
}

function setCoolStyle() {
  var savingTheSecondVar = document.getElementById("sug");
  savingTheSecondVar.className = "cool";
}

function setInsaneStyle() {
  var savingTheThirdVar = document.getElementById("sug");
  savingTheThirdVar.className = "insane";
}
```

```css
#sug {
  background-color: black;
}
.normal {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
}
.insane {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
}
.cool {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Struktur.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="struktur.js"></script>
  <title>My first Javascript project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sug" class="cool insane normal">
    <header>
      <h1> Welcome to this Javascript site! </h1>
    </header>
    <section>
      <p>
        text
      </p>
    </section>
    <button type="button" id="normal">First style</button>
    <button type="button" id="crazy">Second style</button>
    <button type="button" id="insane">Third style</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: An ID rule will overrule a class rule. That's how CSS works.

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/  - A nice article on the topic

Comment: Nowadays the de facto standard is to not use ID's for CSS at all - only for javascript.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @ippi.  The #sug selector currently has two jobs: telling your setXStyle functions which element to change, and telling the outer div it needs to start with a black background.  I would change #sug to a dot selector with a new name and make it the only class of the outer div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your CSS.

```
#sug{
   background-color: black;
}
```

Overrides the background-color of your classes because it is a more specific selector (i.e. an id selector).

change the rest of your classes in the css to include the id like

#sug.normal, #sug.insane, #sug.cool etc.

Here is a nice article on CSS specificity to help you understand more: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

That's because an id has preference over a class. You will need to specify it like this:

```
#sug.cool { background: red; }
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing the background-color provided by the #sug id in CSS onClick() events of the buttons.
Id has more preference over classes

It is a good habit to use below code as classes has spaces between them and it can be used if you want to add more than one class.

```
messageBox.className += " " + "normal";
```